# Do I still have to worry about memory alignment if am dividing an already allocated chunk of memory into smaller pieces?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, memory-management

I am writing a program in C, on an x86 and/or 64-bit Windows platform. I have used `VirtualAlloc` to allocate a large chunk of memory. Now in my program I am going to divvy that memory space up among various parts of my program at runtime using what amounts to a memory allocator that I wrote myself. The data that will be packed into this chunk of memory includes things like bitmaps, wav files, etc. The Windows constant `MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT` is defined as 8 on 32-bit versions of the OS and 16 on 64-bit versions. My question is, do I still care about aligning this data along 8 or 16 byte boundaries if I've already allocated a contiguous (already aligned) chunk from `VirtualAlloc`?  It is trivial to add the padding bytes to my allocator if necessary, but I don't know if I really need to.

To be clear, let's say I have

`void* Chunk = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 33554432, MEM_RESEVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);`

So now I have 32MB of memory that the OS has already aligned for me. If I subdivide that 32MB chunk of memory up myself among various pieces of data, should those subdivided regions of memory *also* be aligned on 8 or 16 byte boundaries?

Comment: We don't know. It all depends on the requirements of the clients of your heap manager. If clients have specific alignment needs, then you need to address those. If they don't, then you don't have to align chunks. The question is kind of useless, really. It's like asking *"I know, I should obey the traffic lights at them huge crossroads. But should I also do so at the smaller ones?"*

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your input. But your analogy is garbage at best, or a straw man otherwise. To use your parlance, if I can get away with not obeying the traffic lights at the smaller intersections, without hurting anybody, then why shouldn't I?

Comment: Exactly. If nothing else, my *"garbage"* analogy actually made you use your brain. In trying to dismiss it as useless, you merely re-instated my initial premise: We don't know. Only you can answer the question. And you just did. If you can get away with it, then by all means, go ahead and do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the chunks of that memory block need a particular alignment depends on how they will be accessed by the code.  If you do not know how the code accesses this memory, you should align the chunks by rounding the offset up to a multiple of `MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT`. Otherwise, you might invoke undefined behavior if the code accessing the chunk makes an invalid assumption and accesses the unaligned memory with some instructions that command a specific alignment.

On the x86 architecture, with common settings, byte, word, double and quad word accesses can be made on misaligned adresses, but MMX and AVX instructions do require 16 byte alignment and generate exceptions if done on unaligned addresses.

Comment: It sounds like I should just add padding bytes just to be on the safe side, especially since it's so easy to do, and I do intend on accessing said data with MMX instructions. No problem.

Comment: @RyanRies: as explained above, if you intend to use MMX instructions, and the compiler might do this on its own, definitely align the chunks.